# There is a way to split the a string using that I have to send with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm tring to send, about 60/80kb with a node.js socket, but I have this error:

```
 events.js:72
         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
 Error: read ECONNRESET
     at errnoException (net.js:884:11)
     at TCP.onread (net.js:539:19)
```

If I send more than 54Kb I  have this error, but if I send 33kb I have no error.
There is a way to split the file that I read in my server socket?

code here:

```
            console.log("1");
            var fs = require('fs');
            console.log("2");
            var profileText = fs.readFileSync('/tmp/profile','utf8');
            console.log("3");
            var pageHtlm = createProfile(profileText);
            console.log("4");
            fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/profile_server", pageHtlm);
            console.log("5");
            var encyptedProfile = sjcl.encrypt(resKey[0],pageHtlm);
            console.log("6");
            fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/profile_server_cifrato", encyptedProfile);
            console.log("6");
            sock.write(fs.readFileSync(encyptedProfile,'utf8'));
```

thanks a lot

Comment: try using a stream to write to the the `sock`. Look at [fs.createReadStream](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options)

Comment: sorry but I'm not a nodejs programmer, how can I do it?

Comment: What socket is that ? Which module are you using ?